# How mock mongo.ErrNoDocuments with mtest in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, testing, mocking, mongo-go

I have this function:

```golang
func CheckExistUser(documentNumber string, mongoClient *mongo.Database) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    colletionUsersName := "my-collection"

    colletionUsers := mongoClient.Collection(colletionUsersName
    filter := bson.D{{Key: "cpf", Value: documentNumber}}

    user := &entity.UserEntity{}
    err := colletionUsers.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(user)

    if err == mongo.ErrNoDocuments { // uncovered test here
        return models.ErrAccountNotFound // uncovered test here
    }

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I want to test the line `if err == mongo.ErrNoDocument`. I made a test mocking generic error and success.

This is my generic error test

```golang
func TestFindOneWhenMongoReturnsError(t *testing.T) {
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    mt.Run("success", func(mt *mtest.T) {
        fakeError := mtest.WriteError{
            Index:   1,
            Code:    200,
            Message: "generic error in mongo",
         }
        mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateWriteErrorsResponse(fakeError))

        documentNumber := "12345678900"

        err := repository.CheckExistUser(documentNumber, mt.Client.Database("mongodb://mock"))
        assert.ErrorContains(t, err, fakeError.Message)
    })
}
```

This works like a charm. But work only for these lines

```golang
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

I cannot make the function `FindOne` return the instance `mongo.ErrNoDocuments`.
How can I do to test this line:

```golang
if err == mongo.ErrNoDocuments {
```

Answer (score 2):

To mock the result of a [`Collection.FindOne()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.FindOne) call, you (also) have to create and use a cursor response, composed of a single batch of course, and the batch (list of result documents) should be empty. (A `FindOne()` operation is also a `Find()` operation with an implicit `limit=1`.)

Here's how you can do it using [`mtest.CreateCursorResponse()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest#CreateCursorResponse):

```
mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateCursorResponse(
    0,
    fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", "dbName", "collName"),
    mtest.FirstBatch,
    // no documents listed here on purpose
))
```

If you would want the cursor to contain / return documents those could be listed as the final variadic argument, here I intentionally left that empty, so the cursor will return no elements.

This will result in `FindOne()` returning `mongo.ErrNoDocuments`.

Here's a complete test:

```
func TestFindOneWhenUserDoesntExist(t *testing.T) {
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    mt.Run("ErrAccountNotFound", func(mt *mtest.T) {
        mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateCursorResponse(
            0,
            fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", "dbName", "collName"),
            mtest.FirstBatch,
            // no documents listed here on purpose
        ))

        documentNumber := "12345678900"

        err := CheckExistUser(documentNumber, mt.Client.Database("mongodb://mock"))
        assert.ErrorIs(t, err, models.ErrAccountNotFound)
    })
}
```

Here's a page with many more examples of using [`mtest`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest): https://medium.com/@victor.neuret/mocking-the-official-mongo-golang-driver-5aad5b226a78

Comment: Worked :)) Thanks for this o/